# How can I host a Asp.NET Core gRPC Service on IIS

Tags: iis, grpc

I need to host my Asp.NET Core gRPC Service on IIS so that I can make it publicly available for others in my team so can you please provide a proper document or steps for hosting my gRPC service on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#server-options) states that ASP.NET Core gRPC can be hosted on IIS, but it carries extra requirements.

- IIS requires .NET 5 and Windows 10 Build 20300.1000 or later.
- HTTP.sys requires .NET 5 and Windows 10 Build 19529 or later.

So please check if it meets the requirements before trying to publish it on IIS:

[Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

Hosting .net core application in IIS is not yet supported. For more details please go through [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9020)