# How to host .net core gRPC service for access from anywhere?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, grpc, hosting, grpc-web

I wrote a web service application ( not web site ).
My web service receives web request using gRPC over .net core 6 - and send back Reply.

I looking for a way to host my service and let anyone on the same domain to using my web service.

I saw on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71825648/how-can-i-host-a-asp-net-core-grpc-service-on-iis) questions on stackoverflow that i can't host my service on IIS for access from anywhere in the same domain.

How can i host my service on windows or linux?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I succeed to do it is by doing self-host
I will be happy to have more solutions:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(5000, o =>
                    {
                        o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                    });
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```